# Variation of Donsker's Invariance principle

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots$ be i.i.d. with mean 0 and variance 1. What can be said about the functional limit of $W^{n}_{t}:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{l_{n}}}\sum_{j=[\alpha_{n}t]-l_{n}+1}^{[\alpha_{n}t]}X_{j}$, $0\leq t\leq 1$, for any monotone sequence $\alpha_{n}$? Of course, $l_{n}$ is an increasing sequence tending to $+\infty$. I think Donsker's theorem should be the right tool for that type of question. But I am not able to write it down rigorously.

Comment: $W^n_t\stackrel{\text{dist.}}{=}\frac1{\sqrt{l_n}}\sum_{j=1}^{l_n}X_i$, since $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ be i.i.d.

Comment: Please check the subscript in the definition of $W^n_t$, $i,j$ and $t$.